# 'Notify user of new account' checkbox to be selected as default

Tags: users, 6

What I am trying to do is have the 'Notify user of new account' checkbox selected as default when creating a new account.

I have been trying similar steps as to http://drupal.org/node/1059168 but the solution posted in the comments is for D7, I need it for D6.

Any ideas, on how I could change this code for D7

```
<?php

/* Hook form alter
 * Sets "notify user of new account" chosen by default
 */
 function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
     $form['account']['notify']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

to have it work with D6?

Or any helpful links I mat have missed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found here - http://drupal.org/node/1295268#comment-5060488

```
<?php
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
    if ($form_id == 'user_register') {
        $form['account']['notify']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
    }
}
?>
```